# Axios post IN Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am attempting an axios POST, using Node js.
making a call to the api is in two steps, first doing a post to get an access token, then  a get with that access token.

I have accomplished the call in c#

```
  var baseUri = new Uri("www.example.com");

            var requestToken = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri(baseUri, "oauth/token"),
                Content = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=someIDnumHere&client_secret=somePassword")
            };


            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestToken).Result)
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        var json = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;                  

                        dynamic jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

                        var accessy = jsonData.access_token;

                        accessTokens.Add(accessy.ToString());


                    }
                }
```

and even Firefox REST Client

but I have failed (bad request) in node JS

this is what I tried.

```
 let urly = 'https://example.com';


  const newPost = {
      body: 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=someIDHereclient_secret=somePasswordHere'
  };
  
  const sendPostRequest = async () => {
      try {
          const resp = await axios.post(urly, newPost);
          console.log(resp.data);
      } catch (err) {
          // Handle Error Here
          console.error(err);
      }
  };
  
  sendPostRequest();
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: could you try `const newPost = { grant_type: 'client_credentials', client_id: 'someIDHere', client_secret: 'somePasswordHere' };`

Comment: tried 
const newPost = { grant_type: 'client_credentials', client_id: 'someIDHere', client_secret: 'somePasswordHere' }
and
const newPost = { "grant_type": 'client_credentials', "client_id": 'someIDHere', "client_secret": 'somePasswordHere' }

Comment: You don't need to set newPost as an object with 'body'.  Just pass the string as the second argument in axios.post(). Also make sure you are sending the right headers and any query string params you might need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ zemaj

```
let urly = "https://example.com";

const sendPostRequest = async () => {
  try {
    const resp = await axios.post(
      urly,
      "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=someIDHereclient_secret=somePasswordHere"
    );
    console.log(resp.data);
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle Error Here
    console.error(err);
  }
};

sendPostRequest();
```